# How to make recycler view scroll more than the height of the items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view starting from top of screen going to the bottom of screen.
At the bottom of screen there is one more view which hides the last item of recycler view.

I want recycler view to scroll a bit more, up to the top of the bottom element. So the last item could be visible.

I know, like i can add some dummy empty item at the end of list in recycler view. But i do not want to disturb the number of items in the recycler view.
Should i resize the height of the last item of the recycler view so that its content comes above the bottom element?

Anyone has some better idea.
whats the best way to do it?

Comment: share your xml code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the answer.
need to set this in recyclerview

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="the bottom padding needed"
```

Comment: Thats even better than dummies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set height of recycler view to **match_parent**. Use Relative Layout and change properties of recycler vie relative to the view (which you want to add at the bottom of screen).
for Example. Layout_above

**OR**
You can simple use ScrollView to scroll the whole view.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this approach will cut the view above the item, he needs the recycler scroll behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the root view of your layout a ScrollView:
Something like:

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
       <RecyclerView/>
       <TheItemsYouWantToSee/>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You can have different containers instead of the LinearLayout: CoordinatorLayout, Constraint... that wraps the items inside the scrollview

Comment: scrollview can hold only one direct child.

Comment: Then put all items inside a LinearLayout , and this linear inside the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Add your recyclerview and that bottom view you want to keep inside a RelativeLayout like this -

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <RecyclerView/>
   <YourAnotherView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And, add the `layout_above` property to the RecyclerView. This property will keep the recyclerview above your bottom view, always.

Comment: layout_above property will take the id of the YourAnotherView as value, please note.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy View works fine. And more importantly it's less messy. Just add as mush dummies you need to be above that `View` and make them invisible at the start of `onBindViewHolder`

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        //two more items (invisible) for end of the list
        return  list.size + 2
    }
```

and in before populating the items `onBindViewHolder`

```
if(position >= list.size) {
            holder.item.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            return
        } else
            holder.item.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```